# the difference of Vuforia text recognition and OCR?

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract, text-rendering, vuforia

Could someone please tell me what is the difference of Vuforia Text Recognition and OCR? are they the same? I am a little confused because from what I had found is that Vuforia can recognize text without the need to capture any image whereas OCR applications such as Tesseract requires the user to capture and image to recognize the text.

Thank you.

Comment: +1... I, too, wonder how these two technologies differ from one another. I am familiar with the concept of `Augmented reality`, but this question just got stuck in my mind. Please acknowledge me if you recieve proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my mind this is incorrect comparing "Vuforia Text Recognition" and "OCR".  Another way to phrase it is to say Vuforia platform has OCR capability.  Using a similar example, one could say Adobe Acrobat has OCR capability.  Vuforia is a specific proprietary platform capable to perform computer vision tasks, one of which can be OCR.  OCR is a generic term (vendor-independent) that describes a computational process of converting image-based pixel data to digital characters.  OCR can be implemented in different ways using different methodology and formulas (neural networks, pattern matching, statistical, etc.), and I am sure Vuforia Text Recognition came up with their own somewhat unique way, like everyone else.  Now it probably can be added to list of available OCR tools (I have not tried Vuforia yet).

Ilya Evdokimov
(WiseTREND)

Answer (score 3):

Vuforia has data set and only finds words in that dataset. So if your image has word "bazinga", and data set stored in vuforia framework does not have that word, it will not find it for you from image.

On other hand, Tesseract is pure OCR. So it will find individual characters/words. Tes

Answer (score 0):

OCR is a normal method to extract text from pictures, and it maybe realized in algorithms, Vuforia has one, and other company may has another.

Normally this algorithm is very security.